# GWT Autobeans and Dates

Tags: java, json, gwt, autobean

I am trying to use AutoBeans, i am parsing json that has a date such as '2011-12-08T10:07:24.247-05:00' to a Date variable in my bean,  but StringQuoter.tryParseDate() always returns null. Also if i had a string "2011-12-08" can i not specify a formatter that will return a date such as what piriti allows you to do this using @Mapping(value = "date", format = "dd.MM.yyyy"), as shown here http://code.google.com/p/piriti/wiki/ExternalMappings